# Minimal most lightweight Qt build

Tags: qt, configuration, build

Is there a way to remove some uneeded locale to reduce the size of Qt Core ?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Please focus on one issue per question.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit to match with the answer proposed and ask separated questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to be more specific about what your application requires. Regardless, I'd recommend reading through [this thread](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2014-May/012236.html) on the interest mailing list, as it has some interesting information regarding slimming Qt Core. In particular, you can reduce the size of ICU:

> I'll leave it for others to pass comment on the standard configure
>   options and size, but if you're really desperate for every last saving
>   then removing the locales you don't need can save you 230 KB (on Linux
>   64bit it reduces my default release build from 5.5MB to 5.2MB), but
>   it's a manual process:
>
> 1. Download http://unicode.org/Public/cldr/24/core.zip and unzip
> 2. Run "../path/to/qt5/qtbase/util/local_database/cldr2qlocalexml.py
>      core/common/main  >> qlocale.xml"
> 3. Edit qlocale.xml to remove all the locales you don't need: only
>      remove  groups from inside  and nothing else, I
>      suggest you always keep C and en_US in addition to the locales you
>      require.
> 4. Run "../path/to/qt5/qtbase/util/local_database/qlocalexml2cpp.py
>      qlocale.xml  ../path/to/qt5/qtbase/"

Comment: The OP was asking for plugins and qml, not (only?) locale , QtCore, ICU, as far as I can tell. I think the OP was specifically too broad. :)